# identify an item in json and update key and value in it

Tags: json, shell, select, key, jq

my input json  is given below , i want select if  "Name": "bot-block" then  update it's ​"Action": to "Block": {} from  "Allow": {},i performed this this using select command but it filters my json and only returns the item with .Name=bot-block,i want updation in json not filtering .this is my current command `jq  '.[] | select(.Name=="bot-block") | .Action |= . + { "Block" : {} } ' input.json`

```
   [
{
 "Name": "searchblock",
 "Priority": 3,
 "Action": {
   "Block": {}
 },
 "VisibilityConfig": {
   "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
   "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
   "MetricName": "searchblock"
 }
},
{
 "Name": "bot-block",
 "Priority": 4,
 "Action": {
   "Allow": {}
 },
 "VisibilityConfig": {
   "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
   "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
   "MetricName": "user-agent"
 }
}
]
```

expected output

```
    [
{
  "Name": "searchblock",
  "Priority": 3,
  "Action": {
    "Block": {}
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "searchblock"
  }
},
{
  "Name": "bot-block",
  "Priority": 4,
  "Action": {
    "Block": {}
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "user-agent"
  }
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly "assign" to the `Action` element of the selected array item. `|=` only affects the selected item, but the output of the filter is still the entire input.

```
jq  'map(select(.Name=="bot-block").Action |= {Block: {}})' input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Super close! It's just a precedence issue.

```
.[] | select(.Name=="bot-block") | .Action |= . + { "Block" : {} }
```

should be

```
( .[] | select(.Name=="bot-block") | .Action ) |= . + { "Block" : {} }
```

because `|=` has lower precedence than `|`.

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/M4Shs3c8Co)

Think of `foo | bar |= baz` has modifying `foo | bar` but returning `foo`. As such, the original snippet returns the modified `.[] | select(.Name=="bot-block")`, while the fixed version returns the modified `.`.